# Use paket in legacy solutions

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget, paket

We have several legacy solutions with the following folder structure:

- root-folder

  - Solutions

    - Solution 1

      - BuildOutput
      - Sulution 1.sln
      - ...
    - Solution 2

      - BuildOutput
      - Sulution 2.sln
      - ...
    - Solution 3

      - BuildOutput
      - Sulution 3.sln
      - ...
  - Software

    - DotNet

      - Projects

        - Project 1

          - Project 1.csproj
          - ...
        - Project 2

          - Project 2.csproj
          - ...
        - Project 3

          - Project 3.csproj
          - ...
        - Tests

          - Test Project 1

            - Test Project 1.csproj
            - ...
          - Test Project 2

            - Test Project 2.csproj
            - ...
        - WPF Projects

          - Wpf Project 1

            - Wpf Project 1.csproj
            - ...
          - Wpf Project 2

            - Wpf Project 2.csproj
            - ...

All solutions have some common projects with other solutions.

Now we use nuget as package manager. Is it possible to use paket instead with this folder structure? And if yes, how. I tried the convert-from-nuget, but this doesn't work.

Comment: It should be possible (`paket` does recursive folder scans when you do actions), but what problems are you running into when using `convert-from-nuget`? If you have stuff that misues Nuget dependencies (like stuff manually referring to assemblies that Nuget manages), then you will have to do manual fixing of those problems in project files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The team of Paket answered the question very well on github (https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/issues/965).

I have to run `convert-from-nuget` from the `root` folder, not the `solution` folder.

> Paket is always looking down, never sideways or a up.

Then I have to restrict / correct the `paket.dependecies` definition if needed. I needed to restrict to .net 4.0 framework version because of Unity nuget package.

At least I had to execute `paket install --hard` for clean install of all packages.